# Android capture new outgoing call

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Redirect outgoing calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683494/android-redirect-outgoing-calls)

The requirement is to replace newly dialed number with another one. I have captured the ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL event and used Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER to get the current outgoing number and then I have used setResultData inside my class(which extends BroadcastReceiver) to replace the dialed number. Basically code is,

```
if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(action)) {

   String phonenbr = 
    intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
   Log.d("OutGoingNum", "phonenbr is " + phonenbr);

   if (phonenbr.startsWith("00")) {
    setResultData("12345678");
   } 
  }
```

My code works fine in Android emulator but on the device the code works only on Redial. It doesnt work when you dial the number via dialpad. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that Android won't allow the interception and replacement of a dialed number.  It would be far too easy for someone to abuse this.

Comment: It does allow and i have done the project :)

Comment: Nice to know... thanks for passing the word Rita.

Comment: Rita - can you share how you did it?

Comment: It looks like Rita hasn't been around since Feb 11. Might want to look at other questions around like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683494/android-redirect-outgoing-calls) which has an answer by Rita stating she found her solution.