# Android: Redirect outgoing calls

Tags: java, android, redirect, emulation

I'm trying to *redirect outgoing calls to a different phone number* on an Android device. So, I use a BroadcastReceiver "listening" for the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL intent, on his onReceive() method I use the setResultData() method to change the phone number.

Like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    
    setResultData("351978923221");

}
```

In the emulator all goes well, but on my real device (a crappy ZTE X850 with Android 2.1 I believe) it doesn't if the calling Intent originates in an Activity which is part of the same application. After the dialing screen appears, the phone terminates the call.

Any thoughts out there on why this happens?

**Note:** I know my question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493287/android-capture-new-outgoing-call) but I chose to ask it again anyway to provide additional details about what goes wrong.

---

**Manifest File**

An excerpt...

```
    <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallDetection" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
                    android:priority="9999" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest? Also can you add some error checking in there and see if it picks anything up (ie. the number it was trying to dial). "Log.v('onReceive', 'phone number: ' + intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER));" - the key is the see if it's even getting there to begin with.

Comment: Just added the parts that matter of the manifest file. I will get back on this latter today and post add new information.

Comment: I got it to work in certain conditions, I think the problem has to do with the phone number that gets to the BroadcastReceiver or set with setResultData(). e.g. If the phone number I try to call starts with my country's prefix, 351 it must have + has the first character to work, if it has only the phone number it works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I cut the dialed call and redialed the new call. It worked perfectly on the device.

This is the code part:

```
setResultData(null);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", "!Number to be dialed!", null);
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(newIntent);
```

Hope this helps.